# Prototype.js creating problems with InfiniteCarousel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code that works fine in the webpage:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.infinitecarousel3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="easing.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#carousel').infiniteCarousel({
            imagePath: 'images/'
        });
    });
</script>
<!--<script src="prototype.js"></script>-->
```

However, as soon as I uncomment The `prototype.js` line it gives an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'infiniteCarousel' of null.

The `prototype.js` file is from  http://prototypejs.org/ and I'm using it for some other function. I have Googled a lot but am unable to come up with a solution - how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Prototype.js library is taking over the `$` global variable. You can assign the $ variable to jQuery within the scope of your document.ready shortcut in this way:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.infinitecarousel3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="easing.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function($){
        $('#carousel').infiniteCarousel({
            imagePath: 'images/'
        });
    });
</script>
<!--<script src="prototype.js"></script>-->
```

The `$(document).ready()` function, and its shortcut `$(function(){})`, sends the jQuery factory function as the first argument to its callback. Naming that argument `$` will scope a local $ variable as jQuery within that function.

In the future, I suggest bringing jQuery in **after** prototype, and using the `jQuery.noConflict` method to relinquish jQuery's control of `$`. You can then assign the $ function back to jQuery only inside functions where it's necessary, using the IIFE wrapper:

```
// prototype code using prototype's $ out here
(function($){
    // jQuery code using jQuery's $ goes here
}(jQuery));
```

In this particular case, you don't need to do that because the `$(document).ready()` method already does it for you. But you should grow used to that tool.

And you should replace Prototype. :)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I'm new to web programming and actually understood half of what you said. Why should I replace Prototype?

Comment: No problem! Replace Prototype because jQuery and Prototype are competitors: including them both will run a lot of superfluous, duplicate code in your client browser. It's a good idea to standardize on one DOM manipulation library, and these days jQuery is the de facto standard. It's likely that whatever Prototype is doing, jQuery or plain JS could do.